# Please combine the ildasm and ilasm tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

The [ildasm](/questions/tagged/ildasm) and [ilasm](/questions/tagged/ilasm) tags look like dupicates of each other. However, I don't have enough score in those tags to propose synonyms.

Comment: The things aren't the same thing at all though.

Comment: @AakashM, but to a large extend people are using the tags as if they are the same.

Comment: Just because people use it that way doesn't mean that it is or should be that way. In this case we need to educate people. *(This feels so strangely familiar...)*

Answer (score 11):

[ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) is the MSIL ***disassembler*** and [ilasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) is the MSIL ***assembler***.  While I can agree that there are plenty of questions where one or the other is used incorrectly, the fact is that they are two different sides of the same coin.

The tags shouldn't be merged, but questions that are mistagged should be fixed.

Comment: Should the tag be renamed to make to clear, e.g. to msil-disassembler etc

Comment: @IanRingrose: That might be a good solution.